# Winforms: How to Replace Single Button Image Color (e.g. white) with Disabled Color (e.g. gray) When Enabled Set to False

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I am looking for white regions of button image to turn gray when Enabled is set to false. The text is currently drawn in front of the button with the color changing appropriately (i.e. when Enabled is set to false it turns gray). Currently, BackgroundImage is set to the button image with BackgroundImageLayout set to Stretch so it fits across entire button. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  If it's an image, you want to change the image colors?  If so, then it's not "button" help you want, but `Bitmap` instead.

Comment: Incidentally, I would approach the problem with two images and swap the image as the button state changes.  Modifying the image color on-the-fly seems like an unnecessary hassle.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the image swapping approach. I was hoping for something designed in specifically for this.

Answer (score 1):

If your enabled value is from a check box, then you should be able to wire up the eventhandler of the checkbox to do the updating for you. see example below

```
private void checkbutton_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           if(checkbutton.checked)
                 //change button image to disabled
           else 
               //switch to other button image type

      }
```